# Implicit conversion for multiple parameters

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

Is it possible to implement in Scala an implicit conversion for the group of parameters (without defining them as some class member) like

```
implicit def triple2One (x :Int, s :String, d :Double) =  x  // just as an example
```

So that I would be able to call it in the code like

```
val x :Int = (1, "test", 2.0)
```

Comment: From your example, I think that closest you can get to the desired result is by defining an implicit conversion for `Tuple3[Int, String, Double]` (can also be short-handed in the argument as `arg : (Int, String, Double)`)...

Comment: Ok seems to be good. Tuples are limited to Tuple22 right?

Comment: Yup, same as `FunctionN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible:

```
scala> implicit def iFromISD(isd: (Int, String, Double)): Int = isd._1
iFromISD: (isd: (Int, String, Double))Int

scala> val x: Int = (1, "two", 3.0)
x: Int = 1
```

Naturally, there has to be a type annotation on the resulting `val` to drive the search for and application of the implicit conversion.

**Addendum**

It occurs to me there's another way that doesn't involve dubious implicit conversions:

```
scala> val (y, _, _) = (1, "two", 3.0)
y: Int = 1
```